Finding the minimum of a cubic between w₀ and w₁ under certain conditions.
Let $$P(w) = a + bw + cw^2 \tag{1}$$ be a known parabola, where $c > 0$.
This parabola has a minimum in $(\frac{-b}{2c}, a - \frac{b^2}{4c})$.
Let $$w_1 = \frac{-b}{2c} \tag{2}$$ the w-coordinate of the vertex of $P$.
Define the cubic $$Q(w) = d + ew + fw^2 + gw^3 \tag{3}$$ such that
$$\begin{align}
Q(w_0) &= P(w_0) \\
Q'(w_0) &= P'(w_0) \\
Q''(w_0) &= P''(w_0) \\
Q(w_1) &= P(w_1) + h
\end{align} \tag{4}$$
For some $w_0 \neq w_1$.
It can be shown that if $h=0$ then $Q(w) = P(w)$, as also trivially follows from
the fact that the four equations of (4) precisely define $Q$ (there is only one possible solution for $Q$) and $P$ itself would clearly satisfy all four equations if $h=0$.
Thus, if $h=0$ then $Q$ has a minimum precisely at $w=w_1$.
Empirically (by graphing it with a computer program) it is easy to see that this minimum moves towards $w_0$ when $h$ is made larger (but never reaches it, after all $w_0 \neq w_1$ and therefore $Q'(w_0) = P'(w_0) \neq 0$ (namely $P'(w_1) = 0$)).
Moreover, when $h$ is made negative, this minimum moves the other way and there is no minimum between $w_0$ and $w_1$.
Empirical conclusion
There is exactly one minimum of $Q$, between $w_0$ and $w_1$, if and only if $h > 0$ and no minimum otherwise.
Question
Where does the minimum between $w_0$ and $w_1$ happen?

Lets start with filling in the equations of (4) and solving $d$, $e$, $f$ and $g$.
$$\begin{align}
Q(w_0) = d + e w_0 + f w_0^2 + g w_0^3 &= a + bw_0 + cw_0^2 = P(w_0) \\
Q'(w_0) = e + 2f w_0 + 3g w_0^2 &= b + 2c w_0 = P'(w_0) \\
Q''(w_0) = 2f + 6g w_0 &= 2c = P''(w_0) \\
Q(w_1) = d + e \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right) + f \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^2 + g \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^3 &= a + b \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right) + c \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^2 + h = P(w_1) + h
\end{align} \tag{5}$$
working this out gives
$$\begin{align}
d &= a + \alpha w_0^3 \cdot h \\
e &= b - 3 \alpha w_0^2 \cdot h \\
f &= c + 3 \alpha w_0 \cdot h \\
g &= -\alpha \cdot h
\end{align} \tag{6}$$
where
$$\alpha = \left(\frac{2c}{b + 2c w_0}\right)^3 = \frac{1}{(w_0 - w_1)^3} \tag{7}$$
Verification:
$$\begin{align}
Q''(w_0) &= 2f + 6g w_0 \\
&= 2c + 6 \alpha w_0 h + 6 (-\alpha h) w_0 \\
&= 2c \\
Q'(w_0) &= e + 2f w_0 + 3g w_0^2 \\
&= b - 3 \alpha w_0^2 h + 2(c + 3 \alpha w_0 h) w_0 + 3(-\alpha h) w_0^2 \\
&= b - 3 \alpha w_0^2 h + 2 c w_0 + 6 \alpha w_0^2 h - 3 \alpha h w_0^2 \\
&= b + 2c w_0 \\
Q(w_0) &= d + e w_0 + f w_0^2 + g w_0^3 \\
&= a + \alpha w_0^3 h + (b - 3 \alpha w_0^2 h) w_0 + (c + 3 \alpha w_0 h) w_0^2 + (-\alpha h) w_0^3 \\
&= a + \alpha w_0^3 h + b w_0 - 3 \alpha w_0^3 h + c w_0^2 + 3 \alpha w_0^3 h - \alpha h w_0^3 \\
&= a + b w_0 + c w_0^2 \\
Q(w_1) &= d + e \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right) + f \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^2 + g \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^3 \\
&= (a + \alpha w_0^3 h) + (b - 3 \alpha w_0^2 h) \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right) + (c + 3 \alpha w_0 h) \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^2 + (-\alpha h) \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^3 \\
&= a + b \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right) + c \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^2 + \alpha w_0^3 h - 3 \alpha w_0^2 h \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right) + 3 \alpha w_0 h \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^2 - \alpha h \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^3 \\
&= a + b \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right) + c \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^2 + \alpha \left(w_0^3 - 3 w_0^2 \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right) + 3 w_0 \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^3 \right) h \\
&= a + b \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right) + c \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{2c}{b + 2c w_0}\right)^3 \left(\frac{(2c w_0)^3 + 3 (2c w_0)^2 b + 3 (2c w_0) b^2 + b^3}{(2c)^3} \right) h \\
&= a + b \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right) + c \left(\frac{-b}{2c}\right)^2 + h
\end{align}$$
Thus
$$\begin{align}
Q(w) &= (a + \alpha w_0^3 h) + (b - 3 \alpha w_0^2 h) w + (c + 3 \alpha w_0 h) w^2 + (- \alpha h) w^3 \\
&= P(w) + h \alpha \left(w_0^3 - 3 w_0^2 w + 3 w_0 w^2 - w^3 \right) \\
&= P(w) - h \alpha (w - w_0)^3 \\
Q'(w) &= P'(w) - 3 h \alpha (w - w_0)^2 \\
&= b + 2c w - 3 h \alpha (w^2 - 2 w_0 w + w_0^2) \\
&= (b - 3 h \alpha w_0^2) + (2c + 6 h \alpha w_0) w - 3 h \alpha w^2
\end{align}$$
Note that if $h = 0$ then this has a zero if $b + 2c w = 0$ (aka $P'(w) = 0$) in other words if $w = \frac{-b}{2c} = w_1$. Otherwise if $h \neq 0$,
$$w = \frac{-(2c + 6h \alpha w_0) \pm \sqrt{(2c + 6 h \alpha w_0)^2 - 4 (- 3 h \alpha) (b - 3 h \alpha w_0^2)}}{-6 h \alpha}$$
Because $c > 0$ we are only interested in the solution with the $+$; the other solution goes to infinity for small $h$.
Lets define $\beta = 6 h \alpha$ then the zero occurs at
$$\begin{align}
w &= \frac{2c + \beta w_0 - \sqrt{(2c + \beta w_0)^2 + \beta (2b - \beta w_0^2)}}{\beta} \\
&= \frac{2c + \beta w_0 - \sqrt{(2c)^2 + 2 \beta (b + 2c w_0)}}{\beta} \\
&= \frac{1 + \frac{\beta w_0}{2c} - \sqrt{1 + 2 \beta \frac{b + 2c w_0}{(2c)^2}}}{\frac{\beta}{2c}} \\
&= \frac{1 + \frac{\beta w_0}{2c} - \sqrt{1 + 2 \beta \frac{w_0 - \frac{-b}{2c}}{2c}}}{\frac{\beta}{2c}} \\
&= \frac{1 + \frac{\beta w_0}{2c} - \sqrt{1 + \frac{\beta}{c} (w_0 - w_1)}}{\frac{\beta}{2c}} \\
&= \frac{1 + \frac{\gamma}{2(w_0 - w_1)}w_0 - \sqrt{1 + \gamma}}{\frac{\gamma}{2(w_0 - w_1)}}
\end{align}$$
where
$$\gamma = \frac{\beta}{c} (w_0 - w_1) \tag{8}$$
And thus the zero occurs at
$$w = w_0 + 2\frac{\sqrt{1 + \gamma} - 1}{\gamma} (w_1 - w_0) \tag{9}$$
Note that this means that if $\gamma$ goes to $+\infty$ then the zero occurs at $w_0$, while if $\gamma$ approaches $0$ then $\sqrt{1 + \gamma} \rightarrow 1 + \frac{\gamma}{2}$ and the zero becomes $w_1$. Therefore, the zero lays in between $w_0$ and $w_1$ for positive values of $\gamma$.
$$0 < \gamma = \frac{\beta}{c}(w_0 - w_1) = \frac{6h \alpha}{c}(w_0 - w_1) = \frac{6h \frac{1}{(w_0 - w_1)^3}}{c}(w_0 - w_1) = \frac{6h}{c(w_0 - w_1)^2}$$
which is positive only if $h > 0$.
